# How to add value to set from another set?

Tags: java, set, java-stream

I have `Set<RollingField> rollingFields` and I need to add field to another set: `Set<String>`

Now I have code like:

```
Set<String> fieldNames = new HashSet<>();
rollingFields.forEach(e -> fieldNames.add(e.getMeta().getName()));
```

How can I change it to one line like (my way is not working)?:

```
Set<String> fieldNames1 = rollingFields.stream().map(rf -> rf.getMeta().getName());
```

Comment: `rollingFields.stream().map(rf -> rf.getMeta().getName()).collect(toSet());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already almost done. You just need to collect the stream results to a set:

```
rollingFields.stream().map(rf -> rf.getMeta().getName()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, you just need to collect the stream you have to a set:

```java
Set<String> fieldNames1 =
    rollingFields.stream().map(rf -> rf.getMeta().getName()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```